# How do I write a mod in Assembly with an if conditional?

Tags: assembly

I'm currently trying to write this if conditional as a line in assembly. How would I do this?

`if iterator%2==1`

Comment: what instruction set and what assembly language for that instruction set (what assembler)?

Comment: If this is in a loop, usually it's easier and better to unroll the loop so the branch condition becomes constant.  (Assuming you handle startup somehow with a branch.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're testing the remainder from a division by 2. Just look at the lowest bit!

```
  test dword [iterator], 1   ; Lowest bit has VALUE 1
  jnz  IsTrue
IsFalse:
  ...
IsTrue:
  ...
```

Or use the `bt` instruction:

```
  bt   dword [iterator], 0   ; Lowest bit has INDEX 0
  jc   IsTrue
IsFalse:
  ...
IsTrue:
  ...
```

Don't know if it can occur in your program, but if the iterator happens to be a negative number then the remainder from dividing by 2 will never be 1. (See [1201ProgramAlarm's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63441343/how-do-i-write-a-mod-in-assembly-with-an-if-conditional/63441399?noredirect=1#comment112182301_63441399))

If the spirit of your instruction `if iterator%2==1` is to differentiate between **odd** and **even**, then the proposed solutions still hold. *IsTrue* matches *IsOdd* and *IsFalse* matches *IsEven*.

Comment: This gives a different result than the OP's code if `iterator` is negative (because the remainder will be negative or zero, not 1).

Comment: Note that `test` performs a lot better than `bt` here due to the bit string semantics.

Comment: @fuz: `bt mem, immediate` isn't too bad ("only" 2 uops), it's the `mem,reg` form that's really bad.  But yeah still clearly worse; `test` might macro-fuse with `cmp`, although memory + immediate often doesn't.  Or in 64-bit code, RIP-relative + immediate can't micro-fuse so `test` alone is 2 uops.  (But using static storage for an iterator is a terrible idea; loop vars should go in registers!)  `test byte [mem], imm8` would be more efficient than `test dword [mem], imm32` for code-size reasons.